# Is there a more detailed description of the Battle of Dol Guldur?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

In a recent question, it was mentioned that Galadriel used magic to tear down the walls of Dol Guldur; this, to me, didn't mesh well with my understanding of how magic worked, so I did some investigating. I found a page  for the battle in the [Lord of the Rings wiki](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Dol_Guldur), and it has a lot of information about the battle:

> So then on March 28, Celeborn led many Elves from Lothlórien across the river Anduin in a fleet of Elvish boats. The elves invaded. When they reached Dol Guldur, a defense had already been prepared and the siege endured seven days. As they marched on the fortress, bows strung, a group of orcs mounted on the backs of Wargs and with Giant Spiders charged at them. They were soon shot down. In this time, Radagast came to Dol Guldur as well leading a force of Silvan Elves.
>
> When the fortress was surrounded, on April 6, Galadriel came to the gates and with the power of her Elven ring cast down the walls, foul pits, crevices, caused grasses, and fruit trees to grow. The evil realm of Dol Guldur was finally destroyed. Galadriel caused an Elanor flower to grow in the middle of the old fortress. The forest was cleansed.

Much of it sounds made up to me:

- Galadriel is using the power of her ring, despite the One Ring being destroyed by this time (that might be worth a separate question).
- The battle includes warg riders, giant spiders, and Radagast, which makes this story start to smell of fan-fiction.

I looked at the citations for the wiki page, and it linked to Appendix B of *The Lord of the Rings*. This is what I found there about the battle:

> Celeborn came forth and led the host of Lorien over Anduin in many boats. They took Dol Guldur, and Galadriel threw down its walls and lade bare its pits, and the forest was cleansed.

This is nowhere near the level of detail present in the wiki.

So my question is, **does Tolkien ever provide more detail about this battle?** And/or **is the wiki description based on canon materials or mostly made up?**

Comment: [story-identification] is not the right tag here.

Comment: I thought it fit, since I'm looking for the identification of a story.

Comment: I would recommend Tolkien Gateway (http://tolkiengateway.net) as a more reliable Tolkien wiki.

Comment: It appears that the linked page is now completely different.

Comment: @OrangeDog mission accomplished, I guess.

Comment: The answers are correct that this was fanfiction, but it is likely that Galadriel did indeed 'throw down the walls' with magic. Note that the reference specifically calls out *Galadriel* as doing it, rather than 'the host' or Celeborn, or Celeborn and Galadriel (as a stand in the the army.) The scene calls to mind Luthien's destruction of Tol-in-Gaurhoth: "then Luthien stood upon the bridge, and declared her power: and the spell was loosed that bound stone to stone, and the gates were thrown down, and the walls opened". Remember Galadriel spend a good deal of time with Melian and Luthien!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No it's some form of fan-fiction

All I can find in further works supports what you've seen.

> “and they put forth their strength; and they assailed Dol Guldur, and drove Sauron from his hold, and Mirkwood for a brief while was made wholesome again.”
> <sub>The Silmarillion</sub>

Furthermore the Unfinished Tales and History of Middle-earth don't go into details about the Battle for Dol Guldur, the only other insight is in "The Complete Tolkien Companion" of which the canonicity I'm not sure of.

> “But after the end of the Third Age, the Elves of Lórien crossed the Great River and destroyed Dol Guldur; Celeborn of Lórien and Thranduil of Northern Mirkwood then met in the midst of the Forest and renamed it Eryn Lasgalen ‘The Wood of Greenleaves’ (Sind.).”
> <sub>The Complete Tolkien Companion</sub>

> “in the end, the Elves of Lórien themselves took the offensive, crossing the Anduin eastwards and destroying Dol Guldur.”
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

> “On March 15th forces of Dol Guldur made a great attack upon the Woodland Realm, but although many trees were burned and many Elves slain, Thranduil succeeded in repelling the attacks. Dol Guldur was later destroyed and Thranduil returned to the North.”
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

---

Out of interest, I also did a search for April 6th, and the only thing that brought up was a Hobbit celebration, no form of "attack" by Galadriel.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure there is brief mention of it in The Tale of the Years. Possibly letters too but that's not actually from a memory in my mind so much as it being a possibility. I do know in HoMe there were different discussions about this conflict in a way but not really (I'm not sure how else to describe that so I'll just stop there).

Answer (score 5):

This is completely made up; as a general rule the LotR wiki should **not** be considered a reliable source of information.

Unfortunately the most detailed description of this battle is the one in the Appendices.

Comment: We know you know the drill, merge your accounts, etc.

Comment: Without an explanation of which parts are (and are not) supported in the literature, this answer is pretty worthless and basically just a rant against a website.

Comment: Well..as Richard points out my comment to : **Unfortunately the most detailed description of this battle is the one in the Appendices.** is this: By all means...why not cite it?